# You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I installed the LAMP server in Amazon Linux EC2 instance as described in [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html). Now, the issue is when I try to access `http://publicdns/phpMyAdmin` it is telling me `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server.`

I have tried varies articles trying to fix this, even tried with symbolic links. Since most of the other articles are based on manually install phpMyAdmin, I am unable to get the correct result.

I know I have to access some file and change the the configurations, but I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add your IP under the Allow section in the phpMyAdmin.conf to be able to access your phpMyAdmin remotely.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip my-server-ip-here
       Require ip ::1
       Require ip <your ip>
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from my-server-ip-here
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from <your ip>
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Restart apache post these changes.

Comment: But the issue is how to access this? I mean this file?